# Static property error in Swift enum

Tags: swift

I feel like I'm dancing around an answer on SO with this, but not quite getting it--there are a lot of great and useful questions and answers on static properties in classes, but enums seem to behave a little differently here.

If I have

```
enum Dog: String {
    case Snoopy = "Snoopy"
    case Lassie = "Lassie"
    case Scooby = "Scooby"
    case Astro = "Astro"

    static let fromIndex = [ 0: Snoopy, 1: Lassie, 2: Scooby, 3: Astro ]
    static let all = [ Snoopy, Lassie, Scooby, Astro ]
    static let count = all.count

    func indexValid( index: Int ) -> Bool {
        return 0 ... ( self.count - 1 ) ~= index ? true : false
    }
}
```

*Dog.count* gives the expected 4 in Playground, but *indexValid( 1 )* throws the error **static member 'count' cannot be used on instance of type 'Dog'**

I've tried getters and setters and other types of references with no luck. Is there a way to use a variable like *count* in a function in an enum in Swift?

Comment: Besides the issue, since the enum cases are always static, why do you use a dynamic `count` property? You know that there are 4 cases.

Comment: It's just one less place to maintain when I add a case to the enum, @vadian...

Comment: It's also less performance due to an unnecessary step. Imagine you have hundreds of those things just for your own convenience...

Comment: Performance vs maintenance is a design decision that depends on the particular spec. In this case, I'm more worried about maintenance. @DanielNagy provided 2 nice solutions.

Comment: For String based enums, you don't need to assign values for cases whose name matches the value you want to assign. In you example, this is true for every case.

Comment: Thanks, @TomPelaia, for pointing that out--I probably should have changed the names in the example to match the real world, which includes non-matching strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regular method, like `indexValid` if you refer to `self`, it will refer to the instance.

However, in a `static` method, `self` refers to the type (in this case, to `Dog`) instead of the instance, so you should use `Dog.count`, because therer are no properties on the instance called `count`, it's on the type `Dog`, like:

```
func indexValid( index: Int ) -> Bool {
    return 0 ... Dog.count ~= index ? true : false
}
```

and you should call it like:

```
let dogInstance = Dog.Snoopy
dogInstance.indexValid(5)
```

Or you can use your original version if you make `indexValid` to `static` like:

```
static func indexValid( index: Int ) -> Bool {
    return 0 ... self.count ~= index ? true : false
}
```

and after that calling it will be:

```
Dog.indexValid(5)
```

Comment: That was one of the things that I tried, @DanielNagy, but it threw the error **cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Dog'** Any ideas?

Comment: At which line is this error? At my playground it compiles fine.

Comment: At *Dog.indexValid( 1 )* @DanielNagy--the enum compiles, but calling it throws the error.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should call `indexValid` on an instance right now, since it is not a static method.

Comment: Or change to `static func indexValid(....` and you can use your original version with `self`.

Comment: Just realized I screwed up the boundary in the range, @DanielNagy, and updated it in my original question. Sorry about that, and thanks super for the solution.